# selenium python script is malfunctioning (Python Omagle Bot Script)

Tags: python, selenium

i am programming a simple omagle bot to learn more about the selenium.

**what my scrips should be doing?**

> 1.open the Omegle site, write some interest and press on the text button [this part is working]
>
> 2.it should type the text I defined it to text and then click on Esc button and then repeat this thing properly [this part is partially working]

Below is my script.

```
import random

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


# Settings

tags = ['test']

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
print(">>Opening Browser window : ")
browser.get("https://www.omegle.com/")
print(">>Opening Site : ")
time.sleep(random.randint(2, 4))
print(">>loading page : ")
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

text_area = browser.find_element_by_class_name("topicplaceholder")
text_area.click()

input = browser.find_element_by_class_name("newtopicinput")

for i in tags:
    input.send_keys(i)
    print(">>Tag Entered > " + i)
    input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@id='textbtn']").click()
print("opening a new chat : ")

i = 0
while i <= 50:

    try:
        time.sleep(2)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/img").click()
        print("clicked Next chat button")
    except:
        try:


            time.sleep(10)

            time.sleep(3)
            browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='disconnectbtn']").click()
            print("ESCAPE  pressed ")


            print("waiting for 10 sec")
            # Here messages add as manny as you want
            browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/textarea").send_keys(
                "Hey")
            print("hy sent")
            browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='sendbtn']").click()
            time.sleep(5)

            browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/textarea").send_keys(
                "How are you?")
            print("how are u sent")
            browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='sendbtn']").click()
            time.sleep(10)

            browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/textarea").send_keys(
                "i am steve.")
            print("i am steve")
            browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='sendbtn']").click()
            time.sleep(5)

            i += 1
            print(">Number Of messages send : ", str(i))
        except:
            print("pass")



    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div/div/img").click()
        print("clicked Next chat button")
    except:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='disconnectbtn']").click()
        print("ESCAPE  pressed ")

        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='disconnectbtn']").click()
        print("ESCAPE  pressed ")
```

Comment: what's the error that you are getting?

Comment: i said its malfunctioning ,there is no error ,its just when you run it you will see that it is not working the way it should be

Comment: there is no error because you are swallowing the exceptions.  don't do that.